# How to reload data from url by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

have a method to get all the products

```
 function listProducts() {
    $.get("./listProducts", function(data) {
     data.forEach(function(item) {
      var $clone = $('#product').clone().removeAttr('id');
      $clone.find('.productName').text(item.nameEn);
      $clone.appendTo('#rowProducts');
     });
     });
     };
```

I have another method to add a product, i want when adding a new product, in the success method it does reload to the previous method listProducts() to get the new product list

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validProduct').on("click", function(e) {
     ......
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "./addProduct",
        data : JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 6000,
        success : function(data) {
         /* **reload listProducts** */
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validProduct').on("click", function(e) {
    ......
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "./addProduct",
      data: JSON.stringify(product),
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 6000,
      success: function(data) {
        //recall this function
        listProducts();
      }
    });
  });
});
```